# Picasa installs but is missing in the menu

Tags: 10.10, installation, unity, ubuntu-netbook

Acer Aspire One Netbook
   Ubuntu Netbook Remix 10.10 (freshly installed)
   1 GB Ram 150 GB HDD Space

When I try to install Picasa, it apparently completes, and tells me that it has been installed. But when I try to look for Picasa to run it, it doesn't appear in the menu anywhere.

I am unable to find Picasa on my system and it says that it has been installed already when I try to reinstall it.

I have tried a few things;

- Looked for the key:

  `wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -`

... and then added it.

- Tried the following commands after adding Picasa to my source list:

  `sudo apt-get upgrade`
  `sudo apt-get install picasa`

And here is the result:

```
netbook:~$ sudo apt-get install picasa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
picasa is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

And when I tried to look for Picasa again... I can't find it.

(I had also started [this thread on ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10530070#post10530070) but didn't get a solution.)

---

I tried Jorge's solution and it did launch Picasa immediately, however I am unable to keep it in the launcher. There is no such option. All I can see is only 2 options:
1. Wine
2. Quit

So, I still need help to keep it in the menu/launcher.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a problem with Unity itself:

- [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bamf/+bug/657771)
- Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6222/how-do-i-add-programs-to-the-unity-launcher

#### How it's supposed to work:

Maybe picasa doesn't have a right .desktop file or something. You can do this manually by opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> and typing the command `picasa` and hitting enter.

Then right click on the Picasa icon on the launcher and select "Keep in Launcher"

[image]

Comment: when I hover my cursor over the Picasa Icon, it says 'Wine' and not 'Picasa' :(

Answer (score 1):

If Unity is the launcher specific to UNR, it may not be the problem because I have the same issue with Picasa on Ubuntu desktop 10.04. Works fine after installation, but after rebooting it can be run from the terminal or with alt+F2, but it disappears from the menu and is no longer provided as an option when inserting media.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mistook apt-get update to refresh your package list. You have apt-get upgrade listed in your question.

Comment: that command was provided to me by a fellow Ubuntu user and so I copy/pasted it:)