# Program showing install option after installation

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, wine, software-center

It may be seems duplicate as of [Picasa installs but is missing in the menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29313/picasa-installs-but-is-missing-in-the-menu) but it isn't. In its case, picasa is installed.

I downloaded Picasa.deb file for ubuntu, like I did for google-chrome from google website. When I installed google chrome from Ubuntu Software Center, it first asked for the password, then installed successfully.

Same thing I expect from Picasa.deb file. I did the same, but when it installed, it asks for the password (as in the case of chrome) and installed. But when the installation completes it again shows the Install page. So I thought it is installed. So when I checked, it was not installed. Then I clicked on Google.deb package, it opens in **Ubuntu Software Center** and shows the option of **Reinstall**, that clearly means it is already installed. And when I did the same for Picasa, it is not showing the option of reinstall, instead, it is showing the option of **install**

So I tried to install from terminal.
I write the following command.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i Picasa-package-name.deb
(Reading database ... 172147 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack picasa-3.0.0-build-57.4402.deb ...
Unpacking picasa (3.0.5744-02) over (3.0.5744-02) ...
Setting up picasa (3.0.5744-02) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
```

then

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 421 not upgraded.
```

Then it shows the result

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 421 not upgraded.
```

That still not installed. So am I missing something or where's the problem?

Please Don't Suggest `wine` or `winetricks`. I want to install .deb file not .exe

Comment: What is the output of the commands `sudo dpkg -i Picasa-package-name.deb` and `sudo apt-get -f install` ? Please [edit] your question and add itm or at least the relevant bits.  Google discontinued Picasa in early 2016, so it's no longer supported or updated to work with newer versions of Ubuntu - from where did you download it ? Also, just so you know, the .deb installer is pretty much the same as the exe one which you could install with Wine, just that it comes with a version Wine bundled inside it, instead of requiring wine to be already installed.

Comment: I've heard somewhere, the performance of Softwares run by wine is poorer than using them directly?

Comment: I've edited the question as you asked. Have a look @JonasCz

Comment: Yes, that's true, but in this case the program still uses Wine no matter how you install it - if you install it using the .deb file, it just uses it's own, bundled (it's part of the .deb package) version of Wine. (Google was lazy and didn't want to make a native linux app, so they used Wine instead)

Comment: Ok, so if I didn't find any solution to my problem, I'll install .exe file of Picasa. But for now, is there any solution to the problem I asked?

Comment: Did you check if Picasa icon appears in the dash ? It should be correctly installed already (based on the ouput you posted) - try logging out and then in again (or rebooting), and see if it appears.

Comment: It just showing the icon, but it is not launching, neither I find the option of <b>open with</b> in photos. And it also not showing the option of <b>Reinstall</b> on opening the package in Software Center.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53841/discussion-between-siraj-and-jonascz).